# Record data as array in txt file

Tags: php

I need to create very simple register/login system in PHP. User details must be stored in array in txt file. For some reasons even when PHP not show any error details are not saved to txt file. Any hint?

```
$fullname='';
                     $email ='';
                     $username ='';
                     $password = '';
                     $error = '';

                    $form_is_submitted = false;
                    $errors_detected = false;
                    $clean = array();
                    $errors = array();
                    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    $form_is_submitted = true;
                    if (ctype_alnum ($_POST['fullname'])) {
                    $clean['fullname'] = $_POST['fullname'];
                    } else {
                    $errors_detected = true;
                    $errors[] = 'Please enter your Full Name!';
                    }
                    if (ctype_alnum ($_POST['email'])) {
                    $clean['email'] = $_POST['email'];
                    } else {
                    $errors_detected = true;
                    $errors[] = 'You have enter an invalid e-mail address. Please, try again!';
                    }
                    if (ctype_alnum ($_POST['username'])) {
                    $clean['username'] = $_POST['username'];
                    } else {
                    $errors_detected = true;
                    $errors[] = 'Please enter your user name!';
                    if (ctype_alnum ($_POST['password'])) {
                    $clean['password'] = $_POST['password'];
                    } else {
                    $errors_detected = true;
                    $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid password!';
                    }
                    }



                if ($form_is_submitted === true
                    && $errors_detected === false) {
                    $fp = fopen('filewriting.txt', 'w');
                    fwrite($fp, print_r($clean, TRUE));
                    fclose($fp);
                    } else {
                    echo $errors;
                    }
```

Comment: why do u need it as array??

Comment: Does the file exist? do you have permission to write to it? You say PHP is not showing any errors, do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: Oh god you're writing users' email, username, and plaintext password to a txt file?

Comment: Yes, its not commercial application. Its college project. File exist, I got permission. When I submit the form its display on page Array.

Comment: You have a missing brace for `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {$form_is_submitted = true;` so try `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {$form_is_submitted = true;}` or adding one at the very end/outer part of your code.

Comment: @user2195583 There were other errors besides my comment above. Consult my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

There is a missing brace for

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {$form_is_submitted = true;
```

so it needs to read as

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$form_is_submitted = true;
}
```

You are using [`ctype_alnum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) so when it comes to an email address, the `@` and the dot do not count as alpha-numerical characters `a-z A-Z 0-9`; either remove it `if(ctype_alnum ($_POST['email']))` which proved to be successful in testing this.
You can also use another function such as [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

I quote from the [**PHP manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php):

> **Return Values**
>   Returns **TRUE** if every character in **text** is either a letter or a digit, **FALSE** otherwise.

This block has a misplaced brace

```
                if (ctype_alnum ($_POST['username'])) {
                $clean['username'] = $_POST['username'];
                } else {
                $errors_detected = true;
                $errors[] = 'Please enter your user name!';
                if (ctype_alnum ($_POST['password'])) {
                $clean['password'] = $_POST['password'];
                } else {
                $errors_detected = true;
                $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid password!';
                }
                }
```

Which should read as

```
                if (ctype_alnum ($_POST['username'])) {
                $clean['username'] = $_POST['username'];
                } else {
                $errors_detected = true;
                $errors[] = 'Please enter your user name!';
                } // was missing

                if (ctype_alnum ($_POST['password'])) {
                $clean['password'] = $_POST['password'];
                } else {
                $errors_detected = true;
                $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid password!';
                }
                // } // was misplaced - commented out to show you
```

otherwise it would not have written the password (as part of the array) to file.

Plus this `$error = '';` should "probably" read as `$errors = '';` but that didn't stop it from writing the data to file.

As for the `Array` message, remove the square brackets `[]` from  all instances of `$errors[]`

Answer (score -1):

I think

```
fwrite($fp, print_r($clean, TRUE));
```

should be

```
fwrite($fp, $clean, TRUE);
```

or

```
file_put_contents($fp, $clean);
```